# TEXINPUTS ignored in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: errors, ubuntu, texinputs

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 (default, no tweaking) and I am trying to use pdfLaTeX, like this:

1. the file `z.tex` exists
2. I am in the directory containing `z.tex`
3. `TEXINPUTS` is a shell variable set to `.:~/tex::`  (seems correct and works on other machines with other Ubuntu versions)

Trying to run `latex`, `pdflatex` or `pdftex` gets the same message:

```
I can't find file 'z.tex'
```

Does anyone understand that? What did I forget?

Comment: The last `:` in your value (`.:~/tex::`) is useless. The value `.:~/tex:` gives the same result (an empty directory name in your list of directories).

Comment: I learned long ago that and empty path element in TEXINPUTS inserts the existing value of TEXINPUTS at that point, so that you preserve the old values and add other paths to it. Maybe this is not true anymore. In any case, correcting it from :: to : did not change the result. :(

Comment: First, check if the file is found with `kpsewhich z.tex` If this does not return anything, type `kpsewhich -d 32 z.tex` – with the debug flags http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Debugging – to see where the file is looked for.
It should return something as `[file z.tex] … => found`. If nothing is found, and the looking path seems good, maybe you need to set another variable (I would recommend in any case to always put such compilation variable in a `texmf.cnf`)

Comment: There's *never* a need to add the current directory in `TEXINPUTS`, because it's always looked at first.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! We usually do not include greetings or thanks in the questions. Please visit the faq and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384 for more information on the site.

Comment: But the value `dir:` already contains two names (separated by `:`): `dir` and the _empty name_. In `TEXINPUTS`, an _empty name_ denotes all the system directories.

Comment: That was the point: if a.tex already exists on TEXINPUTS and you want to replace it with your own version from a local directory, you must put it before the default.

Comment: It seems to search on the right places and right order: kdebug:start search(files=[z.tex], must_exist=0, find_all=0, path=.:/home/prof/oliveira/tex::.:/home/prof/oliveira/.texmf-config/tex/kpsewhich//... (long list follows)).
kdebug:search([z.tex]) => (empty, no result)

Answer (score 3):

Solved: it was not a tex-related problem.

The filesystem containing the files was mounted by mount.cifs and it seems that it has to be mounted with additional flags (nobrl and noserverino) for LaTeX to work properly. LaTeX runs from the local disk and without those flags it tries to reach files on the mounted filesystem, but fails for some reason.

There is a description of the problem in
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1380789